# delete element from list

Tags: python, json, list

i can't delete an element from a list, the list is loaded from a json file.

```
elif choice == 'd':
    # Delete a joke.
    # See Point 7 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
    jokeIndex = input('Joke number to delete: ')
    index = int(jokeIndex)
    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    data = json.load(file)
    data.pop(index)
    file.close()
    print ('Joke deleted')
```

the program seems to run with no errors just it dosnt actually delete the entry (by index) once i load the file the entry is still in there

```
elif choice == 'l':
    # List the current jokes.
    # See Point 4 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    data = json.load(file)
    file.close()
    for (index, entry) in enumerate(data):
        print (index, ')', entry['setup'])
    pass
```

Comment: That's because you are deleting the joke from the list you load. You never actually write the data back out to the file. So the data in the file never changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the list element only, you aren't deleting the element/line from the file.

What you may do is delete the element from the list and overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is write back to the json file. I would use `json.dump(data, file, indent=4)`. See below.

```
# Delete a joke.
# See Point 7 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
jokeIndex = input('Joke number to delete: ')
index = int(jokeIndex)
file = open('jokes.txt', 'r+')
data = json.load(file)
data.pop(index)
file.truncate(0)
json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
file.close()
print ('Joke deleted')
```

Comment: raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 260 (char 259)        this is the error i get. I have tryed that solution similiar to what you gave me and once i try to view whats in the json file i get that error

Comment: I'm not sure about that error. I guess it could depend on how your ```.txt``` file is formatted. I assumed something like ```[ "one", "two", "three"]```

Comment: entry = {'setup': jokeSetup , 'punchline': jokePunchLine}              this is the dictionary loaded into the txt file with json as the format